# AJAX response undefined.

Tags: ajax, promise

I am currently creating an AJAX call which queries a controller and returns the appropriate reponse. The only issue is is that the response is coming back as undefined doe to the async nature of the AJAX cal. I am unsure as to how I tell the function to wait for the response. Here is my code:

View:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#payment .membership", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var price = SignUpObject.membershipClick(jQuery(this).attr("data-membership-id"));
        alert(price);
    });
```

Javascript Library Function (which is within an object):

```
var SignUpObject = {
    membershipClick : function(membershipDetailsId) {           
        jQuery.ajax({
            type      :  'POST',
            dataType  :  'json',            
            url       :  'api/membership-choice',
            data      :  'membershipid=' + membershipDetailsId
        }).done(function(response) {
            return response
        });
    }
}
```

The PHP that the AJAX call is calling returns the correct response back so I don't need to include them here. Can anyone tell me how to make the AJAX call wait for a response?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems:

1) You're attempting to call the response synchronously, before the (asynchronous) request has completed.

2) `membershipClick` does not return the request object, so you've got no means of hooking a completion callback onto it.

To fix:

1) Change the line

```
jQuery.ajax({...
```

to

```
return jQuery.ajax({
```

2) Change the line

```
alert(price);
```

to

```
price.done(function(response) { alert(response); });
```

However, the variable `price` would be better named something like `price_request`, since it stores a reference to the request, not the actual price (which is the response.)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
}).done(function(response) {
return response
```

});

For:

```
}), success: function(response) {
return response
```

};

Comment: This is incorrect. Not only is this a syntax error - it ignores the underlying issue completely.